# How to print object properties in template in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services, angularjs-templates

I am new to angular2, And trying to bind object result to the html template. I am able to get data from srtvice by using Observable. I am able to see JSON data in console and in template as well. But when I try to access property from result json, It's not showing data as below image.

[image: Output]

Below is my code of that componenet,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { JuniorService } from '../Service/service.junior';
import { Employee } from '../../models/Employee';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-getjunior',
  template: `<h1>Details of {{id}} 
  <hr/>
  JSON :  {{Junior | json}} 
  <hr/>
  Summary :  {{junior?.summary}}</h1>`
  //templateUrl: './app/Junior/get/junior.get.html'
})
export class JuniorGet implements OnInit
 {

errorMessage: string;
Junior: Employee;
id: number;
private sub: any;

  constructor (private juniorService: JuniorService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

 }

  ngOnInit(){
      this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
     this.getJunior(this.id);
    });
  }

    getJunior(id) {
      this.juniorService.getById(id)
                      .subscribe(
                        data => {
                            this.Junior = data;
                            console.log("Junior data", this.Junior);
                          },
                        error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }


}
```

I am calling service on imit method and that data I want to see in template.

Where else do I need to change to print data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use your code like this

```
{{Junior?.summary}}
```

> there is small typo in your code you are using `junior` instead of `Junior`

and not thorwing any error in console because you have used `safe navigation (?)` in your code

Comment: It's working with your solution :), But I tried same thing before 30 min and it was not working (Not sure what was the issue).
Thanks for answer

Comment: Could you give quick answer for below error for binding property with textbox in 2-way?, 
<input value="{{Junior?.summary}}"  [(ngModel)]="{{Junior?.summary}}" />

Comment: use this `<input value="{{Junior?.summary}}" [(ngModel)]="Junior?.summary" />`

Comment: you cannot use `[(ngModel)]` and `{{}}` simultaneously

Comment: On console -> Error -> 
<input value="{{Junior?.summary}}" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="Junior?.summary" />

Comment: opps my mistake try this `<input value="{{Junior?.summary}}" [(ngModel)]="Junior.summary" />`

Comment: Console -> Error -> TypeError: Cannot read property 'summary' of undefined

Comment: than try to make attribute and event binding diff diff. not to use two way binding, becasue angular will only see `Junior` not its property when template loads

Answer (score 5):

In general, if you want to print an object in your template you can use the following:

```
{{someObject | json}}
```

If the object is observable you can also add `async` like:

```
{{someObject | async | json}}
```